# Angular 13 mixes css and html at production build

Tags: css, angular, npm

My angular production build (ng build --configuration=production) produces the result quoted below. See line 10. So the stye is inlined for some reason. Just this part other styles are properly moved to a css file.
Because of that I am getting error:
**Refused to execute a script for an inline event handler because 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.**

My current nginx settings:
*add_header Content-Security-Policy "object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-elem 'self';base-uri 'self';" always;*

The error red line in development panel in Safari points to the line 10

When I add unsafe-inline flag in the Content-Security-Policy header in nginx the error goes away but this defeats security.
How would I prevent ng build from inlining css ? I am using node 16 and angular 13 and materials.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basket</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <style> <!-- HERE-->
    html, body {
        height:100%
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.99caafd74a8389d7.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.99caafd74a8389d7.css">
    </noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime.42e3e9782c7613ef.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.3a4d88207580181e.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main.664d5eeb134bd6ea.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The source css looks like this:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;}
```

The source html is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set inlineCritical to false in angular.json

Comment: Perfect @MikeOne ! It immediately fixed the problem. I wonder why angular/node developers bother with inlining at all considering it brings security issues.

Comment: As long it’s under your control it’s not a security issue. Inlining is good for performance so it makes sense to use it. You could also just change your csp to allow it?